# How to speed up or parallize a django function with multiple sequential filters and inserts?

Tags: python, django, django-models, algorithmic-trading

I am doing some backtesting in python and have my DB models in Django set up as follows. One is a stock DB keyed by the symbol and one is a price DB keyed by symbol + date. Something like this:

**Stock DB:**

1. FB
2. MSFT
3. Goog

**Price DB:**

1. FB | 1/1/2023 | 150.0
2. FB | 1/2/2023 | 151.0
3. FB | 1/3/2023 | 160

I then run my backtesting algo to do something like

```
for stock in stock_list:
    prices = Price.objects.filter(stock=stock)
    backtest = run_backtest(prices)
```

Basically trying to optimize this for 500-1000 tickers and what I've noticed is the biggest bottleneck is "Price.objects.filter(stock=stock)" since it has to fetch brand new prices for each backtest.

How can I best speed up the filters? Should I try something like loading 5 symbols at a time and then filtering from that? Or a second thread to fetch the next symbol as the first backtest is running? Is there something I'm missing here? I feel like I can speed this up 10-20x easily. Thanks!

Comment: Share your models.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the prices in *bulk* with [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
stock_list = Stock.objects.prefetch_related('price_set')
for stock in stock_list:
    backtest = run_backtest(stock.price_set.all())
```

This will fetch all `Price`s for the (filtered) stocks in one additional query, and do the joining at the Python level.